# Android testing shared preferences

Tags: android, unit-testing

I want to test whether a value is saved correctly to the `SharedPreferences`.

In my code I have the `SharedPreferences` injected so I save a value like so:

```
with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
    putString("testkey", "dummyValue")
    apply()
}
```

In my test:

```
val mockSharedPreferences = mock(SharedPreferences::class.java)
val mockEditor = mock(SharedPreferences.Editor::class.java)

`when`(sharedPreferences.edit()).thenReturn(mockEditor)

assert(mockSharedPreferences.getString("testkey") == "dummyValue")
```

The problem is that the mockSharedPreferences returns null so what else do I need to mock/change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use this code if it returns true your value is saved.

```
public boolean saveUserId(String saveUserId) {
    SharedPreferences 
   sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(USER_DETAILS, 
   MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(USER_ID, saveUserId);
    editor.apply();
    return true;
}
```

and if you want to get the saved value below code is helpful.

```
 public String getUserId(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(USER_DETAILS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(USER_ID,null);
}
```